# WPF Datagrid doesn't display list data

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

I'm working on this thing that requires me to display information inside a DataGrid, I've put the Datagrid, made a List into witch add the data, made sure the AutoGenerateColumns is True and whenever I add a new row I only get this empty rows, not even the headers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16FmG.png)

The code goes as follows:

```
public principal ()
{
  contras = new List<Password>(); //List of things I need to show
}
```

```
private void Add_Pass_But_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            contras.Add(new Password("as", "dfs", "fsalñjd", DateTime.Today)); //Test object
            tabla();
        }
```

```
private void tabla()
        {
            //DataTable dataTable = ToDataTable(contras);
            DataGridPrinci.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            DataGridPrinci.ItemsSource = contras;

            //Other things i've tried
            //DataGridPrinci.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
            //ObservableCollection<Password> obsCont = new ObservableCollection<Password>(contras);
            //DataGridPrinci.ItemsSource = obsCont;
            //DataGridPrinci.ItemsSource = contras.ToArray();

            /*
            DataTable dt = ToDataTable(contras);
            DataGridPrinci.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;*/
        }
```

I've checked a lot of other SO posts but non have really helped me, I keep getting a blank row when I add the test object. I've made it an observable collection, a dataTable, an array...

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection<Password>` instead of `List<Password>`.

Comment: @Clemens - shouldn't matter, because ItemsSource is getting reset everytime (not that this is particular a good idea)

Comment: @RandRandom To the same collection instance each time, so the assignment is ignored by the DataGrid. That matters.

Comment: would OP need to set it to null first and then to the same instance, thought that the setter wouldn't care if its the same instance and still does populate the grid once again because the setter gets called

Comment: ItemsSource is a dependency property. Its PropertyChangedCallback won't be called when the property is set to a value that it already has. If ItemsSource was null before the first call of the `tabla()` method, the DataGrid would be populated once, but who knows.